# Using jsdoc to comment a requirejs module with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, class, requirejs, jsdoc

I'm trying to use jsdoc (Version 3.2.2) and I think it doesn't like my coding style, I can't get the method of my class to show up in it's documentation.

This is what my setup is like:

```
define(["lib"], function(lib){

    var myModule = {};

    myModule.staticMethod = function(param){
        // do something
    }

    myModule.MyClass = function(param){
        // constructor
    }

    myModule.MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function(param){
        // an instance method of MyClass
    }

    myModule.OtherClass = function(param){
        // constructor
    }

    myModule.OtherClass.prototype.otherMethod = function(param){
        // an instance method of OtherClass
    }

    return myModule;
})
```

Following the documentation at http://usejsdoc.org/howto-commonjs-modules.html I added the following jsdoc comments:

```
define(["lib"], function(lib){

    /**
    * @exports myModule
    */
    var myModule = {};

    /**
    * A static Method of myModule
    * @param {string} param A parameter
    */
    myModule.staticMethod = function(param){
        // do something
    }


    /**
    * @class
    * @classdesc This is my class
    * @param {string} param A parameter to the constructor.
    */
    myModule.MyClass = function(param){
        // constructor
    }

    /**
    * A method of MyClass 
    * @param {string} param A parameter to myMethod.
    */
    myModule.MyClass .prototype.myMethod = function(param){
        // an instance method of myClass
    }

    myModule.OtherClass = function(param){
        // constructor
    }

    myModule.OtherClass.prototype.otherMethod = function(param){
        // an instance method of OtherClass 
    }

    return myModule;
})
```

I did not try to document the second class, because it did not work as intended this far. The documentation for `myModule` and `MyClass` are created, `MyClass` belongs to `myModule` and `staticMethod` is documented as a static member of `myModule`. Everything good so far. But `myMethod` is documented as `<static> MyClass#myMethod(param)` at the documentation of `myModule`. I tried to use `@memberOf`, but couldn't get it to work, the following examples all made `myMethod` disappear from the documentation:

```
@memberOf MyClass
@memberOf class:MyClass
@memberOf myModule.MyClass
@memberOf module:myModule.class:MyClass

@memberOf MyClass.prototype
@memberOf class:MyClass.prototype
@memberOf myModule.MyClass.prototype
@memberOf module:myModule.MyClass.prototype
@memberOf module:myModule.class:MyClass.prototype
```

The following made it a member of `MyClass`, but as `<static> myModule.MyClass#myMethod(param)`

```
@memberOf module:myModule.MyClass
```

I tried the @instance tag but that removed `myMethod` from the documentation again.

How can I make `myMethod` show up as an instance method of `myClass`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Perhaps, if so, you could post an answer to your  question? I'm in need of a better understanding of how to comment RequireJS modules also.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. It was in a spare-time project, so not that important to me.

Comment: I found this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172381/how-to-document-a-require-js-amd-modul-with-jsdoc-3-or-jsdoc?rq=1

Comment: @fraxture that one documents a module being ONE class, I tried to have two classes in one module, but I think I will just refactor every class into one requireJS module to make it work. Thanks, though.